# Statistical significance of interface on keypress frequencies

Tags: statistical-significance, frequency, paired-data

I'm doing a comparative study, measuring the number of times a user presses a key in 13 different scenarios, split systematically over two different interface types (A and B). Data was recorded for multiple users in a within-groups design.
I'd like to test the significance of interface types on the keypress frequencies.
How would be best to do so?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. my hypothesis is that "participants will use fewer keypresses to complete a scenario with interface A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a textbook case for a generalized linear mixed model with

- a Poisson or quasi-Poisson response variable
- random effect for user
- random or fixed effect for scenario (depending on whether you treat the scenarios as of interest in themselves, or as more or less just nuisance examples of the range of things you are interested in seeing)
- fixed effect for interface type.

Testing your hypothesis means looking for evidence of the fixed effect for interface type differing from zero.

There are implementations in R and SAS and doubtless in other software.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, and sorry that I'm getting back to you a while later - I'm still not completely sure what significance test I'm looking for - I've had a cursory glance at some methods and I think the one I'm looking for is https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/poisson.test.html? P.S. I think I'll treat it as random effect for scenario for now.

Comment: Actually, I can't treat the scenarios as random because there are different numbers of people in different groups, and some took one set of scenarios more than another. It'll have to be a 2x13 analysis I think...

Comment: Or it might be poisson regression? http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/

Comment: Hi @RachelCabot, yes, that's similar to what I'm suggesting.  "Poisson regression" is just shorthand for "generalized linear model with a Poisson response".  So I'm suggesting Poisson regression, possibly with two levels of random effects (user and scenario).  Simplest to implement is with fixed effects for scenario, so you only get the "usual" single level of randomness, and you could implement just with `glm()` as per your link, rather than needing to get a more complex R package for the mixed effects issue.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I've performed it - just to check - a Pr(>|z|) value less that 0.05 indicates that this effect is a significant predictor, is that correct?

Comment: Or do I need to perform an analysis of deviance on the model in order to tell if interface is a significant predictor?